# insert image to RTF file using PHP

Tags: php, rtf

How can I insert an image to an RTF file. Inside the RTF file there is a placeholder text like {photo}. I want to place the image at this position using php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an open source PHP library that allows insertion of images to PHP-generated RTF documents. It's called [PHPRTF](http://www.phprtf.com/).

Here's the sample code that inserts images: [link](http://www.phprtf.com/samples/index.php/images)

Comment: Yes, i was able to inser the image to an RTF file. I used the RTF standard specification, and placed the hex code of the image preceded by some header values specified in the RTF document.

Comment: When opening in a MS Word, it shows the image, but in Wordpad the image is missing. And I found that when placing the image manually in an RTF file generates some more code. like the same what i generated with the code + some more like

"{\nonshppict" and the same header values + a very large hexa code. Inside that code there was the hex code for the image. But it is in between some other hex values.

I dont know how this other hex is generated...that is on what basis....

Comment: The link to the sample code and library is broken. :-/