# Using PHP to insert an image (via URL) to an existing Word document

Tags: php, rtf

I'm trying to write some PHP that will take a specified RTF document and dynamically add an image to it which is retrieved via a URL.

I've looked into using `PHPRtfLite`; however, based on this [post](http://sourceforge.net/p/phprtf/discussion/804180/thread/e18d4738) it doesn't seem to be possible to modify existing documents.

I'd prefer the image to be inserted at the bottom of the document, so it may be a matter of just reading the document and writing the URL, but I'm not sure how to do this in a manner that fits with the RTF syntax.

Any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: why You want to insert image in RTF document? I think using PHP this purpose will not be solved. But if You want to insert the image in pdf then it's possible with php.

Comment: It's so I can then export the RTF document as a Word document. From my research so far, I thought it would be easier to add the image to an RTF file, then convert to Word, rather than adding it straight to Word.

Comment: Jingo , are You able to convert RTF to word document? have You succeeded? If succeeded then please share the code. I also tried but not succeeded.

Comment: Jingo, what solution You are thiking?

Comment: I'm just creating the word document, saving it as .rtf then just renaming it to .doc. 

I'm still trying to figure something out with regards to a solution

Comment: You may look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135485/insert-image-to-rtf-file-using-php this post. but the open source is also not free...

Comment: Thanks - I looked into that (even linked it in my above post) but it doesn't allow the modification of existing rtf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing two RTF files before and after adding an image you will find that the added data looks like this:

> {\pict\wmetafile8\picw[N]\pich[N]\picwgoal[N]\pichgoal[N] [BYTES]}

- **\pict**    - The picture tag
- **\wmetafile[N]**    - Indicates that the image    type is a Windows
  Metafile. [N] = 8 specifies that the metafile's axes can be sized
  independently.
- **\picw[N]** and **\pich[N]**    - Define the    size of the image, where[N] is
  in units of hundreths of millimeters    (0.01)mm.
- **\picwgoal[N]** and **\pichgoal[N]**    - Define the target size of    the
  image, where [N] is in units of twips.
- **[BYTES]**  - The hexadecimal representation of the image ([bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)).

So, to add an image, we will replace the last occurrence of "}" with the string we built above + "}".
Writing the code should be easier now. :)

Answer (score 0):

An example of insert Image using PHP:

http://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/working-rtf-html-css-and-script-files-with-my-own-packages-java-and-php/

Answer (score -2):

If I was doing what you were doing then I'd use PHP's `FILE_APPEND`

Something like will work for your needs:

PHP

```
<?php
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $location = "image.rtf";

    if(isset($_POST['url'])) {
        file_put_contents($location, $url, FILE_APPEND);
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="./" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="url"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="insert">
</form>
```

Althought there are probably better ways of doing it.

I took the liberty of giving you an example on my testing site [here](http://jamescraig.info/stackoverflow/php/).

Comment: Thanks for the post and the demo, however, that's just inserting the image URL into a file - it's not converting it to the RTF syntax for displaying images :/